# Drawing rectangle around a target on screen

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I am just started with Unity and C#. I need in my work to do rectangle on a scene. I have a 3D scene, say some warehouse and there is an object. Camera is animated and moving towards the object. Is it possible to draw a rectangle around the object on the camera screen while the camera is moving unless the object on the screen? The task is like keeping target in war-flight games.
This is my code, where I tried to draw rectangle anywhere:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MY_getting_images : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject pallet;
    public Camera color_cam;
    public Vector3 pos;
    LineRenderer l;
    void Start()
    {
        pallet = GameObject.Find("PalletWood01");
        l = pallet.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        List<Vector3> ps = new List<Vector3>();
        ps.Add(new Vector3(0, 0));
        pos = pallet.transform.position;
        ps.Add(new Vector3(10,10));
        l.startWidth = 1f;
        l.endWidth = 1f;
        l.SetPositions(ps.ToArray());
        l.useWorldSpace = true;
        /* Finding camera in a scene: tag needed camera, for example "Player", and then GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Camera>();
         * Tag the camera another way for deployment      
               */
        color_cam = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Camera>();
        /*pos = color_cam.transform.position;
        pos = pallet.transform.position;
        Debug.DrawLine(Vector3.zero, new Vector3(0, 0, 5), Color.red);
        Debug.Log(pos);*/
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(pos);
        /*pos = color_cam.transform.position;
        Debug.Log(pos);*/
    }

}
```

The scene now looks like on the image above:
[image]

I want 2d rectangle around the pallet drawn on the screen.

Comment: Presumably you tried doing this with a UI Image sized according to the object's renderer bounds? How have you attempted to draw your rectangle so far, based on the wealth of Unity tutorials freely available for your research, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I got stuck with drawing a rectangle. I started today using Unity and C#

Comment: So [you searched for existing guides about drawing a rectangle](https://www.google.com/search?q=draw+rectangle+unity), right? Which guide did you try following, and where did it not work for you?

Comment: For example this one: https://generalistprogrammer.com/unity/unity-line-renderer-tutorial/
I have read many others, but not found how to draw and keep it in camera screen while the movement

Comment: Great, now edit your question to show the code/scene setup you're using, and explain how the outcomes differ from what you want.

Comment: Thanx for hint!